# Monodroid with Windows Azure Mobile Services

Tags: azure, xamarin.android, azure-mobile-services

I want to add authentication using Windows Azure Mobile Services to a MonoForAndroid app.
Microsoft has [code samples](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-users-dotnet/#add-authentication) to do this for Windows 8, iOS, and Windows Phone 8. 
Xamarin has [announced support](http://blog.xamarin.com/2012/09/20/xamarin-partners-with-microsoft-to-support-azure-mobile-services-on-android-and-ios/) for this but I cant find any sample that covers authentication (most samples are simply TodoItem data access, no authentication at all)

Im new to Mono and Android so converting the C# Win8 sample to Mono for Android is not as straigtforward as I had thought (do they even have support for async await?).

I would appreciate it if someone could point me to a small code sample (or blogpost) to add authentication to a mono for android app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the Xamarin Azure Mobile Services demo here

https://github.com/xamarin/azure-mobile-services

Here is a class that uses the authentication method

https://github.com/xamarin/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/sdk/xamarin/android/src/Microsoft.Azure.Zumo.Android/Core/MobileServiceClient.Android.cs

Authentication is not currently supported for Android devices. That includes applications written in Java and C# using Monodroid.

The only Mobile Services feature currently supported is Data Services using JSON.

The Microsoft SDK hasn't been released for Android yet.

Sit tight though as Azure development is moving swiftly and this feature should be added soon.

Remember the Azure Mobile Services is still in preview and many features available in Windows Phone are not yet available on Android.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 1.1.0 the Mobile Services component for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android has full feature parity with other platforms (Windows Store, WP8, etc), including authentication.

See [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-users-xamarin-ios/) for a tutorial.